# Print the number of activations in a Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, python-3.6

I am attempting to count the number of activations in a model, for example in a LeNet. How could I count the total number of activations?

There is a way to count the number of trainable parameters, however, there does not seem to be an option for calculating individual activations.

Comment: May I ask what did you mean by the number of activations? Are you asking for the number of activation functions or units that pass through them?

Comment: I meant, for example, if you have a convolution let's say a 3x3 kernel that is being applied sequentially on an image. After each convolution the input is summed and then activation can be applied to that particular summation. It is hence not completely proportional to the number of parameters, but it is rather a different number. Thanks for asking, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of activations depends on the layers of the model, for example:

- For a fully connected layer (Dense), the number of activations is equal to the number neurons.
- For a convolutional layer, the number of activation is number of filters times the spatial dimensions of the output feature maps (which depends on padding, input size, etc).
- For a recurrent layer, it depends as LSTM/GRU have a complicated structure. For a simple RNN it is just the number of neurons times the number of timesteps.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there is a way how to extract this information directly from tensorflow, or I should write my own function/script.

Comment: @MartinFerianc I think you need to write your own functionality, some information (like feature map sizes) can be obtained from TensorFlow.

Comment: Ok, I will try and post it here, I thought there will be a way... At least that is what I was assuming, given the downvotes.